# Using the PowerShell host from C# how can I get the output?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-hosting

Having the following NET 5 Console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using var ps = PowerShell.Create();
    // ps.AddCommand("Get-Service");
    ps.AddStatement().AddCommand("Get-Service");
    ps.Invoke();
}
```

The calls seems to be executed with no error, but where the output goes?
I've tried both `AddCommand` and `AddStatement`, and also examined the `ps` variable in debugger, no signs of output. I did discover the `ps.Streams.Information` but it is empty.

Comment: `var results = ps.Invoke();`. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.invoke?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#System_Management_Automation_PowerShell_Invoke)

Comment: many thx, it's an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed in the documentation for the [PowerShell.Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.invoke?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#System_Management_Automation_PowerShell_Invoke) method, it returns a collection containing any results that the PowerShell operation produced.

Thus, you can write

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using var ps = PowerShell.Create();
    ps.AddStatement().AddCommand("Get-Service");
    var results = ps.Invoke();

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```